# Hamcrest When to use Is or equalTo

Tags: java, hamcrest

I'm new using hamcrest. While I'm discovering how to use it I have been a doubt about when to use `is` or `equalTo`.

Is there any difference between `is` and `equalTo`, although it is conceptually or ocasionally? It seems to behave the same.

```
 Assert.assertThat(actual, equalTo("blue"));
 Assert.assertThat(actual, is("red"));
```

Why do you would use one instead of the other?

Comment: `is` internally uses the `equalsTo`. I think its mostly for better readability.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The Javadoc for `Matchers` is pretty clear. `is` in all its overloaded forms is there for expressiveness.

The "main" `is` is `is(Matcher<T> matcher)` which:

> Decorates another Matcher, retaining its behaviour, but allowing tests to read slightly more like an English phrase.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> assertThat(cheese, is(equalTo(smelly)))
> ```
>
> instead of:
>
> ```
> assertThat(cheese, equalTo(smelly))
> ```

`is(T value)` is:

> A shortcut to the frequently used `is(equalTo(x))`.

Allowing `assertThat(cheese, is(smelly))`

... and `is(java.lang.Class<T> type)` is:

> A shortcut to the frequently used `is(instanceOf(SomeClass.class))`.

Allowing `assertThat(cheese, is(DairyFood.class))`

... but this is deprecated in favour of `isA(DairyFood.class)`.

---

What this boils down to is that `is(foo)` and `equalTo(foo)` are exactly equivalent in their behaviour, as long as `foo` is neither a `Matcher` nor a `Class`. You should use whichever you feel communicates your intent most clearly.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Docs](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#is(T)), `is(Object obj)` is just a shortcut for `is(equalTo(Object obj))`, where you can use `is` to compose more expressive matchers.